# Customizing DT with fnRowCallback

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, datatables, dt

I tried to color a whole row inside my datatable with the fnRowCallback argument, the effect works but other DT functions wont work anymore. Here's a simple example:

```
  names <- c("a","b","c","d")
    days <- c(10,5,2,1)

    dat <- data.frame(name=rep(names,days),date=as.Date((Sys.Date()-sum(days)+1):Sys.Date(),origin="1970-01-01"),value=rep(days,days),value2=(rep(days*2,days)))

    datatable(dat,options=list(
    fnRowCallback = JS('function(row,data, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull){
    var d = data[2];
    d = new Date(d);
    c = new Date(+new Date - 12096e5);
    if (d > c)
    $(row).css("background-color", "blue");
    }'),
    rowCallback = JS(
    'function(row, data) {
    if (parseFloat(data[4]) > parseFloat(data[3]))
    $("td:eq(4)", row).css("background-color", "green");
    }')
)) %>% formatCurrency(c("value","value2"))
```

Both fnRowCallback and rowCallback will result in only the effect of fnRowCallback, also formatCurrency is ignored. If you comment out fnRowCallback formatCurrency will work fine together with the rowCallback argument.

This might be a problem with the DT package, but as I'm not that familiar with the javascript datatables library there might be a problem inside my code or an option I'm missing to enable..

Comment: You can maybe try putting the `fnRowCallback` code in the `rowCallback` function. `fnRowCallback` might come from previous versions of DT, might be wrong but I think `rowCallback` replace it as I can't find it in the recent docs. They still kept some backwards compatibility so maybe that's causing the issue.

Comment: That works.. I thought i had to make the fnRowCallback to select all rows, thats what google told me.. Could you maybe elaborate whats the difference between fnRowCallback and the normal rowCallback? Anyway, you can put this as an working answer to my stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fnRowCallback` is the Datatable v1.9 version of Datatable v1.10 `rowCallback` (info [here](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert)). You are essentially setting `rowCallback` twice in your code which is probably causing the issue.

Try putting all your code in the `rowCallback`:

```
datatable(dat,options=list(
    fnRowCallback = JS('function(row,data, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull){

    }'),
    rowCallback = JS(
    'function(row, data) {
    if (parseFloat(data[4]) > parseFloat(data[3]))
        $("td:eq(4)", row).css("background-color", "green");

    var d = data[2];
    d = new Date(d);
    c = new Date(+new Date - 12096e5);
    if (d > c)
        $(row).css("background-color", "blue");

    }')
)) %>% formatCurrency(c("value","value2"))
```

The `rowCallback` function is applied to each row before they are rendered ([docs here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback)).